# ffmpeg capture single window screen freezes with only mouse working

Tags: ffmpeg

**Scenario and Problem:**
I have two machines with windows 8.1 installed. On one computer, every thing works fine with video recording by using gdigrab to capture a window by title. But on the other pc, the desktop recording works fine, but when it comes to capture single window by title, the video freezes with only mouse working. (to be exact, if i play webcam or images in the window being captured, it records the content too, but when some video is played it starts showing black screen or freezed at first frame.

Commandline:
here is the commandline args

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i title="Video - VLC media player" germ.flv
```

What can be the issue on the other pc?

Comment: are both windows displaying using the same output type (like directx vs. direct3d)?

Comment: yes...the output of window is same...a simple window

Comment: i have tried on few other machines two with windows 7,8 and 10..everything works fine there too....

Comment: different graphics cards?

Comment: I just re-installed window and its working now :P